# how can we get a treeview structure with nultiple childnodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, treeview

In my application i need treeview structure with childnodes the appilcation should be in such a way that i can have multiple child nodes with more no of nodes.when user clicks on those nodes it should get expandable how can i do this

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Did you see the `Columns` property?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your mean you can add a extra node as header for example:

```
private void PopulateTreeView(DataTable dtParent, int parentId, TreeNode treeNode)
    {


        foreach (DataRow row in dtParent.Rows)
        {
            string Value = string.Empty;
            string header = string.Empty;
            // this is just extra node for header
            if (dtParent.Columns.Count > 2)
            {
                header += "Name" + " " + " ";
                header += "VehicleType" + " " + " ";
                header += "Capacity" + " " + " ";
            }
            else
            {
                header += "Name" + " " + " ";
            }
            TreeNode headerNode = new TreeNode
            {
                Text = header.ToString(),
                 // Any value that you want and has no confelict with other
                Value = row["Id"].ToString()

            };


            if (dtParent.Columns.Count > 2)
            {
                Value += row["Name"].ToString() + " " + " ";
                Value += row["VehicleType"].ToString() + " " + " ";
                Value += row["Capacity"].ToString() + " " + " ";
            }
            else
            {
                Value += row["Name"].ToString() + " " + " ";
            }

            TreeNode child = new TreeNode
            {
                Text = Value.ToString(),
                Value = row["Id"].ToString()

            };



            if (parentId == 0)
            {
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(child);
                DataTable dtChild = this.GetData("SELECT Id, Name,VehicleType,Capacity FROM Bikes WHERE VehicleTypeId = " + child.Value);
                PopulateTreeView(dtChild, int.Parse(child.Value), child);
            }
            else
            {
                treeNode.ChildNodes.Add(child);
            }
        }
    }
```

or if your mean is finding each column name you can use this:

```
private void PopulateTreeView(DataTable dtParent, int parentId, TreeNode treeNode)
    {


        foreach (DataRow row in dtParent.Rows)
        {
            string Value = string.Empty;
            string header = string.Empty;
            // Get all columns name
            for (var i=0;i<(dtParent.Columns.Count)-1;i++)
            {
                header += dtParent.Columns[i].ColumnName + "  ";
            }

            TreeNode headerNode = new TreeNode
            {
                Text = header.ToString(),
                 // Any value that you want and has no confelict with other
                Value = row["Id"].ToString()

            };


            if (dtParent.Columns.Count > 2)
            {
                Value += row["Name"].ToString() + " " + " ";
                Value += row["VehicleType"].ToString() + " " + " ";
                Value += row["Capacity"].ToString() + " " + " ";
            }
            else
            {
                Value += row["Name"].ToString() + " " + " ";
            }

            TreeNode child = new TreeNode
            {
                Text = Value.ToString(),
                Value = row["Id"].ToString()

            };



            if (parentId == 0)
            {
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(child);
                DataTable dtChild = this.GetData("SELECT Id, Name,VehicleType,Capacity FROM Bikes WHERE VehicleTypeId = " + child.Value);
                PopulateTreeView(dtChild, int.Parse(child.Value), child);
            }
            else
            {
                treeNode.ChildNodes.Add(child);
            }
        }
    }
```